# Exclude all sub-directories from PowerShell Get-ChildItem -match

Tags: powershell

## Goal

Exclude all sub-directories when running a PowerShell script that matches a filename regex pattern

## Directory structure

```
/
- 2018-11-19.md

18-2/
- 2018-10-16.md
- 2019-01-14.md
- 2019-10-10.md

18-3/
- 2019-01-13.md
- 2019-04-25.md
```

## PowerShell script

```
$file = '2018-11-19.md'

Get-ChildItem -recurse | where-object { $_.FullName -match '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.md' } | 
    ForEach-Object {$fullname = $_.fullname; (Get-Content $_.fullname | foreach-object {
        $_ -replace "apple", "orange"
    }) | Set-Content $fullname}

(Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '<p(.*?)>(.*?)</p>', '$2'
    }) | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $file

Get-ChildItem -recurse | where-object { $_.FullName -match '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.md' } | 
    foreach-Object {$fullname2 = $_.fullname; (Get-Content $_.fullname | 
         pandoc -f markdown -t markdown -o $fullname2 $fullname2
    )}
```

## Details

- The goal is to run the PowerShell script **on only file(s) in the root directory**. These file(s) at root will change but always be named according to the convention shown. The regex in the PowerShell script successfully matches this filename.
- Currently the script changes **all files** in the directory example above.
- Any examples I can find show how to exclude specific directories by identifying their names in the script (e.g., `-Exclude folder-name`). I want to exclude **all** sub-directories without naming them specifically because...
- ...In the future sub-directories may be added for 18-4, 19-5, etc., so it seems like an exclusion based on a regex would make sense.

## Attempts

To limit the script's scope to the root directory, I tried variations on `-notmatch` with `\`, `\*`, `\*.*`, `\\*`, etc., without success.

To exclude sub-directories, I tried variations on `-Exclude` with the same paths but did not succeed.

My PowerShell knowledge is not advanced enough to get further than this. I would be grateful for any help or to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you only want the root directory from where the script starts just remove the `-recurse` flag on `Get-Childitem`

Comment: _"on only file(s) in the root directory"_. "Only Files" = `'-Files` switch on `Get-ChildItem`. "root directory" = don't use `-Recurse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Owain and gvee in the comments, when using the -Recurse switch, you tell the Get-ChildItem cmdlet that you wish to traverse through the sub directory structure from the selected location. [As expained on the docs site of the cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Gets the items in the specified locations and in all child items of the locations.
```

So simply removing the switch should make the code do as you want.
If you ever want only X level of sub directories you can use `-Depth` switch.

```
Get-ChildItem | where-object { $_.FullName -match '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.md' } | 
    ForEach-Object {$fullname = $_.fullname; (Get-Content $_.fullname | foreach-object {
        $_ -replace "apple", "orange"
    }) | Set-Content $fullname}

(Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '<p(.*?)>(.*?)</p>', '$2'
    }) | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $file

Get-ChildItem | where-object { $_.FullName -match '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.md' } | 
    foreach-Object {$fullname2 = $_.fullname; (Get-Content $_.fullname | 
         pandoc -f markdown -t markdown -o $fullname2 $fullname2
    )}
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thank you @Henrik Stanley Mortensen